# cache coherence MESI protocol

Tags: caching, synchronization, cpu-cache

This is a bus-based shared memoty multiprocessor system with 2 CPUs, MESI (Illionois) Protocol and write-back caches. Both CPUs access the shared variables B and C. I filled out the following state caches but i'm not sure about what happens after a variable is modified..does it go back to shared state?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When a cache line is written to, the state of the line becomes 'M'.  In all other caches the state becomes 'I'.

Thus the last two lines of your table are not correct.  When P1 writes C, it invalidates the line in P0.  So the 'M' in the P0 cache - VarC should be an 'I'.

A line transitions from the 'M' state to the 'S' state if cache other than the one who has written the line does a read.

Comment: It should also be noted that for MESI, the transition from M to S involves a writeback to memory (since S means unmodified and shared). Adding an Owned (MOESI) or Forwarding (MESIF) state can delay this writeback (and in theory "ownership" of a dirty block could be transferred to further delay writeback but that increases complexity and cache coherence is already one of the "two hard problems in computer science").

Comment: Another core reading the line may also convert an M-line directly to invalid state, if the read asks for it (or in some flavors of MESI where a read is assumed to have a high chance of leading to a write as well)